# WebSocket in ReactJS is setting state with empty array

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-hooks

Thanks in advance for any suggestions here.
I am implementing websocket in ReactJS here and my goal is populating my *history* state with upcoming 'onmessage' events. Oddly to me, *setHistory* is emptying my array after receiving messages from 'websocket.onmessage' events. It even removes my initial state. Simplified version below:

```
function NotificationWebSocket ({object_id}) {
const [history, setHistory] = useState([{text: "The first notification"}]) //

    function connectToWebSocket() {
        const wsStart = (window.location.protocol === "https:" ? "wss://" : "ws://")
        const url = 'localhost:8000/live/'
        let socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(wsStart + url + object_id)
        socket.onmessage = e => {
            console.log(e.data) // logs the received data correctly
            setHistory([...history, {text: e.data}]) // ?? this is setting my history state array to null... ??
            setHistory(history.append({text: e.data})) //also cleans my history array here.
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        connectToWebSocket()
    },[]) // so that we only connect to the websocket once

    return (
        <div>
            We are on a live connection to the server.
            {history.map(item=> <div>{item.text}</div>)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Things to note here:
I am using ReconnectingWebSocket library, although I tried not using it and the same thing occurs.
My connectToWebSocket is being triggered from inside a useEffect cause otherwise I get a couple of websockets requests in the server.

Thanks again,
Felipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a stale closure, this is a common mistake that is often made when using hooks with dependencies (such as `useEffect`, `useMemo`, `useCallback`). Take a look [here](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/).

The solution is to **always include all the variables you're going to use within the `useEffect` callback in the dependency list**. In your case it's hard to spot them, because most of them are hidden inside the `connectToWebSocket` function, which is updated at every render except... the one called by `useEffect` is the one that was created on the **first** render, and the `onmessage` callback closes over the state the component had at the first render.

Since you are using a WebSocket, it's not enough to just `useEffect` every time your `history` changes, because then you'll have multiple connections (one for every change), you also need to disconnect when the next effect is called, and you can do so by returning a function from the `useEffect` callback that disconnects from the WebSocket, so that the effect can connect again. This is also the example that is conceptually explained in React's docs, when showing an [example](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1) about useEffect.

Something that is often suggested to avoid this kind of situation is to

1. Define the function you're going to call within the `useEffect` callback within the callback itself, instead of outside of it;
2. Use your favorite linter to warn you about missing dependencies in your `useEffect` (or similar) calls. If you try `create-react-app`, this is already configured for you.

Also, as @ako-javakhishvili suggests, whenever your next state depends on a previous value of the state itself, call the setter function with a callback instead of an immediate value. This will solve your problem in this case, but you will still have a stale closure and you should take care of that as well.

Comment: Thanks, Juan. I will have a closer look into the the complete guide to useEffect.
If I got it right, I would be connecting and disconnecting to the websocket every time history is updated, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It should not be a problem though, as long as the history doesn't change too much.

Comment: Perfect! Good to have this solution in the pocket, and also thanks for going further on the explanation bringing links to the solution. Appreciate that.

Comment: You're welcome! Remember, I put the bold sentence in the answer not because it's optional and a "best practice", but because it really is a requirement. Failing to do so will lead to weird and very hard to track bugs, I payed that price myself :)

Comment: Yes! I have read The complete guide to useEffect and there is a lot to cover in my app now. I believe my todo list will be cleaned out after that. There as still some things I need to understand better playing with it while coding. But that really helped. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply change `setHistory([...history, {text: e.data}])` with the following code `setHistory(history=> [...history, {text: e.data}])`

Comment: Good. It works! It is an scope issue, as also mentioned by @juandemarco.
In addition, I took juandemarco concerns in consideration and brought connectToWebSocket into the useEffect itself.
This solution seems more straighforward than adding history to the dependencies and connect/disconnect to the websocket.

Comment: The two solutions aren't mutual though. You should use them both, because they solve different issues :)